# How to change the height in between horizontal lines in recharts?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, graph, recharts

I have this graph and need to change the height in between the horizontal lines.

[image]

[**LIVE DEMO**](https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-l2efj1?file=/src/App.tsx:891-1127)

```
<CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip />
  <Legend />
  <Line
    type="monotone"
    dataKey="pv"
    stroke="#8884d8"
  />
```

Comment: Do you specifically want to increase the height between the horizontal lines (in this case the chart height will also increase) or do you want to control the number of lines showed (e.g. show only 3 lines instead 4)?

Comment: @LuisPauloPinto I actually want to reduce the height between the horizontal lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you want, one way to do it is setting the `tickCount` for `YAxis`:

```js
<YAxis tickCount={10} />
```

You can also combine it with `domain` and `interval`:

```js
<YAxis
   tickCount={6}
   domain={["auto", "dataMax + 500"]}
   interval="preserveStart"
/>
```

To better understand these properties:

**tickCount**: *(Number)*

> The count of axis ticks. Not used if 'type' is 'category'.
> DEFAULT value: 5

**domain**: *(Array - optional)*

> Specify the domain of axis when the axis is a number axis. The length of domain should be 2, and we will validate the values in domain. And each element in the array can be a number, 'auto', 'dataMin', 'dataMax', a string like 'dataMin - 20', 'dataMax + 100', or a function that accepts a single argument and returns a number. If any element of domain is set to be 'auto', comprehensible scale ticks will be calculated, and the final domain of axis is generated by the ticks.
> DEFAULT: [0, 'auto']

**interval**: *("preserveStart" | "preserveEnd" | "preserveStartEnd" | Number)*

> If set 0, all the ticks will be shown. If set preserveStart", "preserveEnd" or "preserveStartEnd", the ticks which is to be shown or hidden will be calculated automatically.
> DEFAULT: 'preserveEnd'

To see more about it, you can check recharts API [docs](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/YAxis).

Answer (score 3):

I think by changing height property of LineChart you can achieve your aim:

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={250}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
```

[image]

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <LineChart
      width={500}
      height={400}
      data={data}
      margin={{
        top: 5,
        right: 30,
        left: 20,
        bottom: 5
      }}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try Increasing or Decreasing bottom margin in LineChart Component.

```
<LineChart
  width={500}
  height={300}
  data={data}
  margin={{
    top: 5,
    right: 30,
    left: 20,
    bottom: -20 //Increase or Decrease This
  }}
>
  <CartesianGrid vertical={false} />
  <XAxis dataKey="name" />
  <YAxis />
  <Tooltip />
  <Legend />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="pv" stroke="#8884d8" />
  <Line type="monotone" dataKey="uv" stroke="#82ca9d" />
</LineChart>
```